# MySQL installation from deb, permissions issues

Tags: mysql, linux, permissions

I am trying to install MySQL on ubuntu 14.04 from the deb packages. I am having trouble starting the mysql server, it looks like a permissions problem. I followed the steps outlined [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-debian.html). Downloaded/untarred/installed deb tar bundle.

```
sudo apt-get install libaio1 
tar -xvf mysql-server_5.7.4-m14-2ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb-bundle.tar 
md5sum mysql-server_5.7.4-m14-2ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb-bundle.tar 
sudo dpkg -i mysql-common_5.7.4-m14-2ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i mysql-community-server_5.7.4-m14-2ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i mysql-community-client_5.7.4-m14-2ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i libmysqlclient18_5.7.4-m14-2ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
```

Here is where the files are installed on my system:
All configuration files (like `my.cnf`) are under `/etc`.
All binaries, libraries, headers, etc., are under `/usr`.
The data directory is under `/var`.

Following [these instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/unix-postinstallation.html)

I create a mysql group and user:

```
groupadd mysql
useradd -r -g mysql mysql
```

I change the ownership of mysql scripts to mysql (as per the instructions, but doubt this is necesssary)

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo chown mysql mysq*
sudo chgrp mysql mysq*
```

I run mysql_install_db to set up grant tables

```
sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

I switch back to root the ownership and group of mysql scripts.

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo chown root mysq*
sudo chgrp root mysq*
```

I change the ownership and group of `/data` to mysql. Location is `/var/lib/mysql`

```
cd /var/lib
ls -l mysql
total 122896
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mysql mysql       56 Jul 26 10:17 auto.cnf
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mysql mysql 12582912 Jul 26 10:17 ibdata1
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Jul 26 10:17 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Jul 24 17:36 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 12582912 Jul 26 10:17 ibtmp1
drwxrwxrw- 2 mysql mysql     4096 Jul 24 17:36 mysql
drwxrw-rw- 2 mysql mysql     4096 Jul 24 17:36 performance_schema
drwxrw-rw- 2 mysql mysql     4096 Jul 24 17:36 test
```

Now, when I try to start the `mysql` server, I get permission errors:

```
mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
[4] 5680
/var/lib$ 140727 00:42:17 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid’: Permission denied
140727 00:42:17 mysqld_safe Fatal error: Can't remove the pid file:
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
Please remove it manually and start /usr/bin/mysqld_safe again;
mysqld daemon not started
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 129: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
```

Similarly, if I try to start the server as root:

```
mysqld_safe -p -u root
140727 00:54:08 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
140727 00:54:08 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 129: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 1: eval: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
140727 00:54:08 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 129: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
```

Apparently there are many places where I should be changing permissions, which does not look like the way to go. Three questions:

1. Is there some evident point where I went wrong, or should I just uninstall and apt-get everything?
2. Should I have owner mysql and group mysql for all files that the server needs to update?
3. Is there a comprehensive list of locations where these files are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log. First create the directory if it doesn't exist

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/mysql
```

Next, change ownership

```
sudo chown -R mysql /var/log/mysql
```

and then try again to start the server as root:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
```

If the server does not start paste here the error messages

Comment: After changing the permissions the server starts. error.log contains a few hundred of this warning: `[ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11`,`[ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace`.`[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.`,`[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.`,`[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB`,`[ERROR] Aborting`. Note that after I start the server I cannot stop it, using `mysqladmin -u root shutdown` by calling in any variation of root, password, etc.

Comment: Moreover, on startup mysql server tries to start automatically and fails (likely because it does not start as linux root?). I would really appreciate an explanation of: which files the mysql user needs to be owner [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/unix-postinstallation.html) claims only `/data` needs it, as well as why I can only start the mysql server as linux root (wasn't the whole point of changing ownerships to not have to do that?) -Thanks!

Comment: On startup all processes are started as root (i.e. like `sudo mysqld_safe --user=mysql`). The errors can be seen in the /var/log/messages file too. But failing to lock ibdata1 in the most cases means that you already have mysql server started. Look [here:](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,139843,139843#msg-139843)

Comment: I have accepted the answer, although I am still unclear about the main question I had: On which directories should I change ownership to avoid future permissions issues? Was `/var/log/mysql` the only one, or should I change permissions on all directories created during installation and named `mysql`. I am currently travelling so I thought we can close this for now. I might get back to MySQL questions in a few weeks. -Thanks!

Comment: `--user=mysql` means mysql acts after starting with this user (mysql). So all files and folders needed for proper operation must be fully accessed by this user, i.e. you must set the ownership to user mysql